# Jmeter Performance Testing Logging into application Issue

Tags: regex, testing, cookies, jmeter

I have a issue in logging into a application using **jmeter**.

I used **Proxy server** for recording my login activity.
Once login process is over I

```
stopped the proxy and copied all the files and pasted 
Under Thread group - Http cookie manager - Controller - Login scripts.
```

After running the thread group I get these results

```
[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Host: host.com
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)

the application is cakePHP.
When i view the results in the tree using HTML it shows the Login page.

_method POST
data[User][email_id]    
data[User][password]
```

How can I get the session id.

Comment: Thank u I found the solution.

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: Used regular expression extractor for extracting the cakePHP session id.